# How to use GridSearchCV for polynomials of different degrees?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv, k-fold

What I wanted to do is go over some OLS fits with different degrees of polynomials to see which degree performs better at predicting `mpg` given `horsepower` (while using LOOCV and KFold). I wrote the code, but I couldn't figure out how to apply the `PolynomialFeatures` function to every iteration using `GridSearchCv`, so I ended up writing this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut, KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error



df = pd.read_csv('http://web.stanford.edu/~oleg2/hse/auto/Auto.csv')[['horsepower','mpg']].dropna()

pows = range(1,11)
first, second, mse = [], [], 0     # 'first' is data for the first plot and 'second' is for the second one

for p in pows:
  mse = 0
  for train_index, test_index in LeaveOneOut().split(df):
      x_train, x_test = df.horsepower.iloc[train_index], df.horsepower.iloc[test_index]
      y_train, y_test = df.mpg.iloc[train_index], df.mpg.iloc[test_index]
      polynomial_features = PolynomialFeatures(degree = p)
      x = polynomial_features.fit_transform(x_train.values.reshape(-1,1))   #getting the polynomial
      ft = LinearRegression().fit(x,y_train)
      x1 = polynomial_features.fit_transform(x_test.values.reshape(-1,1))   #getting the polynomial
      mse += mean_squared_error(y_test, ft.predict(x1))
  first.append(mse/len(df))
    
for p in pows: 
    temp = []   
    for i in range(9):      # this is to plot a few graphs for comparison
        mse = 0
        for train_index, test_index in KFold(10, True).split(df):
            x_train, x_test = df.horsepower.iloc[train_index], df.horsepower.iloc[test_index]
            y_train, y_test = df.mpg.iloc[train_index], df.mpg.iloc[test_index]
            polynomial_features = PolynomialFeatures(degree = p)
            x = polynomial_features.fit_transform(x_train.values.reshape(-1,1))   #getting the polynomial
            ft = LinearRegression().fit(x,y_train)
            x1 = polynomial_features.fit_transform(x_test.values.reshape(-1,1))   #getting the polynomial
            mse += mean_squared_error(y_test, ft.predict(x1))
        temp.append(mse/10)
    second.append(temp)      


f, pt = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(12,5.1))
f.tight_layout(pad=5.0)
pt[0].set_ylim([14,30])
pt[1].set_ylim([14,30])
pt[0].plot(pows, first, color='darkblue', linewidth=1)
pt[0].scatter(pows, first, color='darkblue')
pt[1].plot(pows, second)
pt[0].set_title("LOOCV", fontsize=15)
pt[1].set_title("10-fold CV", fontsize=15)
pt[0].set_xlabel('Degree of Polynomial', fontsize=15)
pt[1].set_xlabel('Degree of Polynomial', fontsize=15)
pt[0].set_ylabel('Mean Squared Error', fontsize=15)
pt[1].set_ylabel('Mean Squared Error', fontsize=15)
plt.show()
```

It produces:
[image: graph]

This is fully working and you can run it on your machine to test it out. This does exactly what I want, but it seems really excessive. I am asking for advice on how to improve it using `GridSearchCv` or anything else, really. I tried to pass the `PolynomialFeatures` as a pipeline with `LinearRegression()`, but it could not get it to change the `x` on the fly. A working example would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can specify why your pipeline approach didn't work?  That seems "the right" approach here, pulling results from the `cv_results_` of a grid search for plotting.

Comment: @BenReiniger I do not really know how the pipelines work, to be honest, but I tried passing the degree of the polynomial as an argument to my function, which I included in the pipeline. The problem was that I want ```x``` parameter (df.horsepower in this case)  to be passed to this function so that I can modify it and afterward the fit will be done on the edited version, but there seems to be no way of doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of thing seems the way to do it:

```py
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('poly', PolynomialFeatures(include_bias=False)),
    ('model', LinearRegression()),
])

search = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=pipe,
    param_grid={'poly__degree': list(pows)},
    scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',
    cv=LeaveOneOut(),
)

search.fit(df[['horsepower']], df.mpg)

first = -search.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
```

(negative in that last line because the scorer is negative mse)

And then plotting can proceed more or less the same way.  (We're relying here on `cv_results_` putting the entries in the same order as `pows`; you might want to plot using appropriate columns of `pd.DataFrame(search.cv_results_)` instead.)

You can use `RepeatedKFold` to emulate your loop over `KFold`, though then you'd only get one plot; if you really want the separate plots, then you still need the outer loop, but the grid search with `cv=KFold(...)` can replace the inner loop.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you. Although, this takes twice as much time to compute (compared to my example). I don't understand why. I have even added the parameter ```n_jobs = -1```, but that didn't help. I understand that it should take some time to compute the additional statistics, but the difference should not be that drastic.

Comment: To be clear, by 'time' i mean 'wall time'. CPU time is actually better than in my example, which makes even less sense on a 4-core CPU.

Comment: The timing issue is odd.  The only real difference is that the grid search will refit on the "best" k; you can drop that with `refit=False`.  Everything else is small additions like the extra statistics you mention...

Comment: I have already tried that actually. Just did it once again to be sure, but, unfortunately,  this does not make a difference

Comment: Converting from a dataframe to a numpy array before fitting (adding `.values` in the search's `fit`) helps quite a bit, though still a little slower on a colab instance; I guess repeatedly converting is fairly expensive.  Weird that even after that we're slower though.